JupyterLab Text Editor Themes
In JupyterLab, under Settings, there is a menu item “Text Editor Theme”. This setting allows one to modify the colors of the syntax highlighting within JupyterLab (a) in notebook code cells, and (b) when editing a source code file directly within JupyterLab.
I have a one JupyterLab installation that lists quite a few themes under the “Text Editor Theme” menu item, including:

jupyter
codemirror
abcdef
base16-dark
base16-light
hopscotch
material
mbo
mdn-like
seti
solarized dark
solarized light
the-matrix
xq-light
zenburn

I just installed JupyterLab on another machine that I use, and under “Text Editor Themes” it only lists these two themes:

jupyter
codemirror

What can I do to install the other themes??
P.S. If I search the web for these theme names, they appear to be “codemirror” themes. How can I add them to jupyterlab under “Text Editor Theme”?
Image showing the "Text Editor Theme" menu item:

